# A curious non-abelian continuous structure defined by three different group extensions

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, group-extensions

I am puzzled by the following structure (assume it is a group), called it $G$, contains and satisfies the following ingredients (in particular we can focus on the case that $d=2$). The $G$ contains generators including

1. $\mathbb{Z}/2 \equiv \mathbb{Z}_2^A$
2. $SO(d)$
3. $\mathbb{Z}/4 \equiv \mathbb{Z}_4^B$

The subindices $A$ and $B$ are to specify they are different groups. The group operations of $\mathbb{Z}_2^A$, $SO(d)$, and $\mathbb{Z}_4^B$ satisfy:

- (1) $\mathbb{Z}_2^A$ and $SO(d)$ do not commute:

They obey $\mathbb{Z}_2^A \rtimes SO(d) = Spin(d)$, where $\frac{Spin(d)}{\mathbb{Z}_2^A}=SO(d)$. Namely, we have
$ 1 \to \mathbb{Z}_2^A \to Spin(d) \to  SO(d)  \to 1$.

- (2) $SO(d)$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4^B$ do not commute:

They obey $SO(d) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_4^B =E(d)$, in fact $E(d)$ obeys that
the quotien group $\frac{E(d)}{SO(d)}=\mathbb{Z}_4^B$ and $\frac{E(d)}{\mathbb{Z}_2^B}=O(d)$
and $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_4^B}{\mathbb{Z}_2^B}=\mathbb{Z}_2'$ where $\mathbb{Z}_2'$ is an another mod 2 abelian group. Namely, we have three short exact sequences
$ 1 \to SO(d) \to E(d) \to  \mathbb{Z}_4^B \to 1$, and
$ 1 \to \mathbb{Z}_2^B \to E(d) \to  O(d)  \to 1$, and
$ 1 \to \mathbb{Z}_2^B \to \mathbb{Z}_4^B \to  \mathbb{Z}_2' \to 1$.

We can also write $E(d)$ as
$$E(d)
=\{ (M, j) \in (O(d), \mathbb{Z}_4^B) \; \vert \; \det M = j^2\}$$
where $j \in \mathbb{Z}_4^B$ here can be written as $\{1,i,-1,-i\}$ with $i^4=+1.$

- (3) $\mathbb{Z}_4^B$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2^A$ do not commute:

They obey $\mathbb{Z}_4^B \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2^A  = D_8$ is a dihedral group of order 8. Namely, we have
$ 1 \to \mathbb{Z}_4^B  \to D_8 \to  \mathbb{Z}_2^A   \to 1$.

In summary,
$G$ contain three group generators
$$
 \mathbb{Z}_2^A, SO(d),\mathbb{Z}_4^B
$$
and group operations defined by
$$
\mathbb{Z}_2^A \rtimes SO(d) = Spin(d),\;$$
$$
SO(d) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_4^B =E(d),\;$$
$$\mathbb{Z}_4^B \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2^A  = D_8.
$$

The curious part is that the semi direct products $\rtimes$ are given in a way that $ \mathbb{Z}_2^A, SO(d),\mathbb{Z}_4^B$ can be a normal subgroup repsectively in (1), (2), (3); but  $ \mathbb{Z}_2^A, SO(d),\mathbb{Z}_4^B$ can be a quotient subgroup respectively in (3), (1), (2). So their group operations are cyclic in some way.

So what are the precise constructions/descriptions of the group $G$? Does this generate some familiar groups?

p.s. any comments/partial answers/Refs are welcome!